# The convex hull of rotations does not contain reflections

Tags: matrix-calculus, rotations, convex-geometry, orthogonal-matrices, convex-hulls

$\newcommand{\SO}{\operatorname{SO}_n}$
$\newcommand{\Om}{\operatorname{O}_n^{-}}$
I saw [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89842/what-is-the-positive-part-of-the-unit-ball-in-m-nr?rq=1) the following claim:

Let $\SO$ be the special orthogonal group, and let $\Om$ be the orthogonal matrices of determinant $-1$. Then the convex hull of $\SO$ does not contain any element from $\Om$.

I tried to prove this "directly", and reduced this to the following claim:

Let $A,B \in \SO$. Suppose that
$$
AB^T+BA^T=2\operatorname{Id}. \tag{1}
$$
Then $A=B$. Writing $R=AB^T$, this reduces to proving that if
$$
R+R^T=2\operatorname{Id}, \tag{2}
$$
then $R=\operatorname{Id}$.

Is there an easy elementary proof of this? I were able to show this directly for $n=2$ using the explicit formula for 2D rotation matrices. Using canonical forms, I can reduce the higher dimensional case to the two-dimensional case.

**Is there a proof which avoids using canonical forms?**

I can show that if $R$ satisfies equation $(2)$, then so does $R^n$ for every natural $n$, but I am not sure this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can show $(2)$ implies $R = \operatorname{Id}$, using strict convexity of the norm. We see that, for any $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$,
$$\|Rx + R^\top x + x\| = \|3x\| = \|x\| + \|x\| + \|x\| = \|Rx\| + \|R^\top x\| + \|x\|,$$
hence $Rx$, $R^\top x$, and $x$ are all non-negative scalar multiples of each other. Since all three have the same norm, they must be equal. Thus $x = Rx$. This holds true for all $x$, so $R = \operatorname{Id}$.

Comment: How is $Rx + R^Tx + x = 3x$?

Comment: @lisyarus It is under the assumption of $(2)$. If $R + R^\top = 2\operatorname{Id}$, then this follows immediately.

Comment: Oh, indeed, thank you!

Comment: Thanks, that is a very nice solution which I wasn't expecting. BTW you could use only the sum $|Rx+R^Tx|$, and deduce that $R^T=R$, which together with $R+R^T=Id$ implies $R=Id$.

Comment: @AsafShachar Oh, of course. That's a nice solution too.

Answer (score 2):

Enough to show that every isometric map is an extremal point in $B_1(0, L(E))$, where $E$ is your Euclidian space. For assume that $T$ is a convex combination
$$T = \lambda_1 S_1 + \lambda_2 S_2$$
with $\|T(v)\|= \|v\|$ for all $v \in  E$, and $\|S_i\|\le 1$, $i=1,2$. Then we must have $\|S_i(v)\| = \|v\|$ from the above ( otherwise the inequality will be strict). Since the unit ball in $E$ is strictly convex and $\|T(v)\|= \|v\| = \|S_i(v)\| = \|\lambda_1 S_1(v) + \lambda_2 S_2(v)\|$ we get $S_1(v) = S_2(v)$ for all $v$, and so $S_1= S_2$.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great argument, for a more interesting claim. BTW,  I am curious: Do you know an easy argument for the converse? That is, if a map in the unit ball is not an isometry, then it is not an extreme point?

Comment: @Asaf Shachar: Hi there, another interesting question from you! For the converse, I would use the [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), and reduce to diagonal matrices with elements in $[0,1]$. Then use the fact that every such diagonal matrix is a convex combination of diagonal matrices with entries $\pm 1$ (think of the cube $[-1,1]^n$ ( need $-1$, $1$ and not $0$, $1$ to get unitaries in the middle).

Comment: @Asaf Shachar: It is also that the unit ball in the space of linear endomorphism of the space is not strictly convex, but more like the ball of a $l^{\infty}$.